# How to unlink image in php

Tags: php

i upload image to the server and save the path in data base. Now i want to delete that record and also the image with that record
my code is

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$select=mysql_query("select image from table_name where question_id='$id'");
$image=mysql_fetch_array($select);
@unlink($image['image']);
$result=mysql_query("delete from table_name where question_id='$id'");
```

when i echo $image['image']; this will give me

```
http://www.example.com/folder/images/image_name.jpeg
```

The record is deleted successfully but the image remains there on server.

Comment: Remove the `@` from the unlink call to see whether any errors come up

Comment: `Warning: unlink(): http does not allow unlinking in /var/www/test/delete_table.php on line 11`

Comment: is extension correct? should it not be `jpg` or you can try with path instead of url

Comment: that's your problem right there. Use a file path as @Oezi suggests

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You'll have to use the path on your server to delete the image, not the url.

```
unlink('/var/www/test/folder/images/image_name.jpeg'); // correct
```

you should remove the `@` before `unlink()`, in that case you would have seen the error-message saying "file not found" or something like that.

Comment: but the image path comes from database like i mentioned in my question. so how should i know which image is deleted.

Comment: As of PHP 5.0.0 unlink() can also be used with some URL wrappers. http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Comment: maybe you should have saved the path of the image. another way (i won't ever do that) is to `str_replace('http://www.example.com','/var/www/test',$url);` before unlinking to get the path - but you should really try to avoid this - simply save tha path to the file.

Comment: is there a way to get just the image name with extension from the url.

Answer (score 7):

Simply if you use `folder/images/image_name.jpeg` in place of whole url inside unlink it will work fine
e.g.
    unlink("http://www.example.com/folder/images/image_name.jpeg");

should be replaced with

```
unlink("folder/images/image_name.jpeg");
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use the relative path for delete a file from the server with unlink. If you save the absolute path in your database, first you have to see from what folder you delete the image. so if you delete image from "delete.php" that is in www.example.com/folder/delete.php than you should do something like this:

```
$db_path = "http://www.example.com/folder/images/upArrow.png";
$len = strlen("http://www.example.com/folder/");
$new_path = substr($db_path, $len, strlen($db_path)-$len); echo "  -> ".$new_path;  
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $return = unlink($new_path);
            if($return){echo "Succes";}else{echo "Fail";}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

whenever you select the your code in delete link.
like:`<a href=addproduct.php?action=delete&pid=$get_info[pid]>Delete</a>`
then you have to check the condition using cuurent select item.

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='delete' && isset($_GET['pid']))
{
  $query1=("select * from tablename where id='".$_GET['id']."'");
                                   $result1=mysql_query($query1);
                                while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                                {
                                    $delete=$data['file'];
                                    unlink("../upload/$delete");

                                }
                                $query=("delete from tablename where id='".$_GET['id']."'");
                                $result=mysql_query($query) or die("not inserted". mysql_error());
                                    if($result==TRUE)
                                    {

                                        $_SESSION['msg']="product successfully deleted";
                                        header("Location:addproduct.php");
                                        exit;

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $_SESSION['msg']="error in deleting product";
                                        header("Location:addproduct.php");
                                        exit;
                                    }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//http://www.example.com/folder/images/image_name.jpeg

define("BASE_URL", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("ROOT_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . BASE_URL);

$folder_upload = "images/";

$image_delete = ROOT_PATH . $folder_upload . pathinfo($image['image'], PATHINFO_BASENAME);

if (!empty($image['image'])) {

  /* Delete */
  if (unlink($image_delete)) { 
      echo "<b>{$image_delete}</b> has been deleted";                                   
  } else {
    echo "<b>{$image_delete}</b> error deleting ";                                          
  }

} else {
  echo "File image not exist";

}

// http://localhost/folder/images/image_name.jpeg
```