# WordPress media_handle_sideload() is throwing 500 Internal server error?

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering why this image URL is throwing 500 internal error on media_handle_sideload() without not even allowing the script to pass to error handling section?

> $thumb_url="http://cbproads.com/cbbanners/TBS830043971538.jpg";
>           $post_id='853';
>           $tmp = download_url( $thumb_url );

```
    if( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ){
            echo "error in downloading ".$tmp;
    }


    // Set variables for storage
    // fix file name for query strings
    preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|JPG|jpe|JPE|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|bmp|BMP|png|PNG)/', $thumb_url, $matches);
    //$matches[0]=$tmp;
    $file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
    $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;

    // If error storing temporarily, unlink
    if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
    $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
    if ($debug) { echo 'Error storing temp file! <br />'; }
    }   




    //use media_handle_sideload to upload img:
    $thumbid = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id, $post_title );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you use `path` not `Url`More information [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713888/how-to-unlink-image-in-php)

```
Ex URL : $thumb_url="http://cbproads.com/cbbanners/TBS830043971538.jpg";

Ex PATH : $thumb_url="var/www/cbbanners/images/TBS830043971538.jpg";
```

and you use Path not url link