# Delete specific file from directory as well as delete its name from database array on button click in foreach loop

Tags: php, file-upload

How can I delete the files from array in database, and from directory on button click. I have this code which has deleted all the files in that folder but still showing the file names. I am looking to delete specific file from directory folder and array in database on button click.

```
echo '<ul>';

foreach (explode(',', $msg_rows['msg_files']) as $file){

echo '<li><a href="../files/wcfiles/'.$msg_rows['msg_order_id'].'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>&nbsp
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="../files/wcfiles/'.$msg_rows['msg_order_id'].'/'.unlink($file).'">Delete</a></li>';}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: what you are trying here will not work - you are using `unlink` ~ presumably the php function as a url

Comment: you need to find some basic tutorials, this is not how php works

Comment: This is not how anything works at all

Comment: Well. when I click on the link, I got error forbidden 403.. You don't have permission...

Comment: You really should to give your `unlink` command an `absolute path` rather than a relative path to the file(s) you want to unlink.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit if possible?

Comment: @Martin, I have updated the code but now it has deleted all the files in the folder. I want it to delete specific file from folder, as well as delete its name from array... and it should happen when I click on delete button only....

Comment: unfortunately your question title / text wasn't actually what you're wanting to achieve...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713888/how-to-unlink-image-in-php

Comment: updated the question. I hope it reflects my need...

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the files you get by processing `$msg_rows['files']` you could do something like this:

```
$files=explode(',', $msg_rows['files'] );
foreach ( $files as $file ) @unlink($file);
```

If you are trying to generate a list of files with a link that, when clicked, will delete the file that is a little more involved - most likely would be to use ajax.

```
$files=explode(',', $msg_rows['files'] );
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $files as $file ) echo "<li>$file<a href='#' onclick='deletefile(\"{$file}\")'>delete</a></li>";
echo '</ul>';
```

You would then need to have a javascript function `deletefile` that would send the necessary information to a script that deleted the file. This is a very basic example ( embedding the filename as a parameter )

```
/* javascript */
function deletefile(filename){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ) {
            alert( xhr.response );
        }
    }
    xhr.open( "POST", "/deletefile.php", true )
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("file="+filename+'action='delete');
}
```

Comment: No ram, it doesn't work at all... I have already exploded it. I have all the files separated. all I have to do is to delete the file name from array, and also remove that file from directory